# Troubleshooting Python API Error Message (Highrise API)

Tags: python, api, python-3.x, highrise

I ran this script (https://github.com/mikehking/highrise-analysis/blob/master/highrise-analysis.py) to calculate usage by user for the Highrise CRM system (www.highrisehq.com).  Recently, the script has been returning this error; but I'm not sure what it is telling me -- can anyone help with where I should be looking to fix this?

Thanks

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 557, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1065, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1103, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1061, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 906, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 841, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 133, in connect
    ssl_version=resolved_ssl_version)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util.py", line 619, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 364, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 578, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 805, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:598)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 330, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 590, in urlopen
    raise SSLError(e)
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:598)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mikehking/workspace/highrise-analysis/highrise-analysis.py", line 188, in <module>
    Create_Notes_Backup(PROD_API_KEY, PROD_API_USR, 'highrise-production-notes.bak', 'highrise-production-users.bak', 'highrise-production-people.bak', 'highrise-production-cases.bak', trailing_days = 365) # Production Environment
  File "/home/mikehking/workspace/highrise-analysis/highrise-analysis.py", line 71, in Create_Notes_Backup
    tmp_notes = high.get_person_notes(person.highrise_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/highton/highton.py", line 436, in get_person_notes
    return self._get_notes(subject_id, 'people')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/highton/highton.py", line 433, in _get_notes
    highrise_type, subject_id)), Note)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/highton/highton.py", line 115, in _get_data
    content = self._get_request(endpoint, params).content
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/highton/highton.py", line 44, in _get_request
    params=params,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 55, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 455, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 558, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 385, in send
    raise SSLError(e)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:598)
```

Answer (score 1):

The last traceback suggests that the script is trying to `Create_Notes_Backup`, but encounters an error when communicating with the Highrise API.

The error message:

> ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:598)

is consistent with a server that accepts your connection but then closes it immediately or prematurely. This might be a firewall issue.

If you have OpenSSL installed on this machine, you can try something like this to check the connection:

```
openssl s_client -crlf -connect USER.highrisehq.com:443
```

where `USER` is your Highrise user. You should normally get a long TLS handshake trace full of technical details, ending with `---` and then it waits for your input.